# Not able to access array element in react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am receiving a json data of single student from the server. Here i can easily get this.state.info.Firstname but i can not able to access this.state.info.Father.Firstname. How can i access this??

this is my react code:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Information extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            info:' '
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        let self = this;
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/studentById')
            .then(function(data) {
                //console.log(data);
                self.setState({info:data.data});
            });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <pre>
                  <ul>
                    <li>{this.state.info.Firstname}</li>
                    <li>{this.state.info.Lastname}</li>
                    <li>{this.state.info.DateOfBirth}</li>
                    <li>{this.state.info.PlaceOfBirth}</li>
                    <li>{this.state.info.Age}</li>
                    <li>{this.state.info.Months}</li>
                    <li>{this.state.info.Nationality}</li>
                    <li>{this.state.info.MotherTongue}</li>
                    <li>{this.state.info.BloodGroup}</li>
                    <li>{this.state.info.Father.Firstname}</li>                
                  </ul>
                </pre>
            </div>);
    }
}
export default Information;
```

this is my json data:

```
{ _id: 5899b77c0ce1d10b723ab4ac,
  Id: 92,
  Firstname: 'Surya',
  Age: 11,
  Lastname: 'G',
  DateOfBirth: '11-11-11',
  PlaceOfBirth: 'Bangalore',
  Months: 2,
  Nationality: 'Indian',
  MotherTongue: 'Kannada',
  BloodGroup: 'B+ve',
  ResidentialAddress: 'Vijayanagar 3rd cross, Bangalore',
  EmergencyContactNumber: 
   { Address: 'SIT',
     PhoneNo1: 1234,
     PhoneNo2: 123455,
     Relationship1: 'Uncle',
     Relationship2: 'Aunty' },
  Mother: 
   { Firstname: 'Joe',
     Lastname: 'S',
     Occupation: 'Business',
     PlaceOfWork: 'Bangalore',
     OfficialAddress: 'Jayanagar',
     EmailId: 'jjj@gmail.com',
     PhoneNo: 12345,
     MobileNo: 1234567890 },
  Father: 
   { Firstname: 'Chandra',
     Lastname: 'S',
     Occupation: 'Business',
     PlaceOfWork: 'Bangalore',
     OfficialAddress: 'BTM',
     EmailId: 'cc@gmail.com',
     PhoneNo: 12345,
     MobileNo: 1234567890 } }
```

Comment: r u getting any error, when using `this.state.info.Father.Fullname` ??

Comment: yes..like this i am getting : Cannot read property 'Firstname' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is, you defined `info=''` in state, and fetching the data from `server`. You are updating the `info` value once you get the data from `server`. You are making the `api call` in componentDidMount method, that used to get called after `component` is `mounted` successfully. When it tries to render `{this.state.info.Father.Firstname}`, before you got the `response`, it is throwing the `error` because value of `info` is `''` at that time, so you need to put a check in `render` method and wait until you didn't get the `response`, Use this it will work:

```
return(
    <div>
        {this.state.info != '' ?
            <pre>
              <ul>
                <li>{this.state.info.Firstname}</li>
                <li>{this.state.info.Lastname}</li>
                <li>{this.state.info.DateOfBirth}</li>
                <li>{this.state.info.PlaceOfBirth}</li>
                <li>{this.state.info.Age}</li>
                <li>{this.state.info.Months}</li>
                <li>{this.state.info.Nationality}</li>
                <li>{this.state.info.MotherTongue}</li>
                <li>{this.state.info.BloodGroup}</li>
                <li>{this.state.info.Father.Firstname}</li>
              </ul>
            </pre>
            :
            null
        }
    </div>
)
```

Comment: u defined `info:'  '`, instead of that  define it like this: `info:''` or change the condition i used, use it like `{this.state.info!= ' '}` . use the same value in condition that u defined in constructor.

Comment: Thanks bro. Can u explain wat was the problem?

Comment: plz check the answer for explanation, reason is, initial value of info='', and you were trying to access the `Father.Firstname`, `this.state.info.Father` was undefined, and you cant access any value of undefined. 
run this in console: `a={}; console.log(a.b, a.b.c);`

Answer (score 0):

The info state you are using should be a object ,you are using as a string, may be that caused the issue. Try using this . Rest all code remains the same.

```
` constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            info: { }
        }
    }`
```